# How to save HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, save, html5-canvas

Currently I am using [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) to save the content of my HTML5 canvas. It doesn't appear to work in Google Chrome, however. Any ideas on how to work around the issue are welcome. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`canvas.toDataURL()` appears to work fine in Chrome, so it may be a library issue. The "convert canvas to image" functionality seems to work, though.

Comment: Okay. The library uses toDataUrl and "document.location.href" for providing save dialog. Apparently "document.location.href" isn't supported by Chrome.

Comment: Any progress with this: is it possible to get a Save As... dialog in Chrome as for Firefox?

Answer (score 5):

use this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="canvas2image.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="savecanvas" value="Save Image" onclick="savecanvasfile()"/>
</body>
</html>



<script>
function savecanvasfile(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_name');
    Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
}
</script>
```

download these canvas2image.js and base64.js and save it in local folder for the working of this code.

These will be available in the site
https://web.archive.org/web/20140904002425/http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: Interesting approach but you cannot choose the file name, or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah!! But I cannot choose a name while I'm running it in Chrome. But Firefox browser prompts for the file name to save it. How this can be resolved??

Comment: In my case Firefox asks for saving the file, not for changing its name. A workaround for Chrome and IE (HTML5) without touching anything server-side is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906142/how-to-save-a-png-from-javascript-variable/15504286#15504286 . No solution yet for Firefox.

Comment: Why are you assigning `context` and `strDataURI` when they are never used?

Comment: The linked website is dead.

Comment: From the archived website, looks like [`canvas2image.js`](https://web.archive.org/web/20140904024323/http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/canvas2image.js) does what [canvas.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) does. For the saving, it replaces the image mime type with `"image/octet-stream"` and then sets `document.location.href` to the generated data url.

Answer (score 4):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
document.write('<img src="'+strDataURI+'"/>');
```

Comment: Why did you include `var context = canvas.getContext("2d");`, when `context` is not being used?