# Saving PNG files with FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, blob, filesaver.js

I'm trying to use FileSaver.js to download PNG files that are being served from my express app. The files are being sent as base64 encoded strings, but when I try to use FileSaver.js to save them they become corrupted.

This is the way I'm trying to save them:

```
var blob = new Blob([base64encodedString], {type: "data:image/png;base64"});
saveAs(blob, "image.png");
```

I've also used this method of saving the images, but it doesn't work if the base64encodedString becomes too large:

```
var download = document.createElement('a');
download.href = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64encodedString;  
download.download = 'reddot.png';
download.click();
```

What am I doing wrong with the FileSaver.js?

Comment: Check the base64 string and make sure it displays the image, you can use an online base64 converter for this if you need to. it might be corrupted before you send it to the File Saver so check that it's valid first.

Comment: @JoshLeeDucks I've been trying to convert it using an online tool, but haven't had any success, but when I use the second method for downloading the (smallest) images it works so it should work for the Blob method too.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that you'll probably want to write it to a Canvas first.

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504286/3649914)

```
base_image = new Image();
base_image.src = Base64String
```

canvas into a blob

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('YourCanvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
// Draw image within
context.drawImage(base_image, 0,0);
```

then you can use FileSaver.js to save it

and finally save it

```
x_canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
saveAs(blob, "screenshot.png");
}, "image/png");
```

A nice fiddle was also created for this in that post  [Click Here For Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khhmm/9/)