# Fetch API Download File

Tags: javascript, c#, fetch-api

I feel like I'm so close to getting this right.
In this example the file is 125 KB and of type image/png.

I have a C# controller method that constructs a HttpResponseMessage with a file as follows:

```cs
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
{
      var file = await _api.GetFileAsync(id);

      var httpResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      httpResult.Content = new ByteArrayContent(file.Bytes);
      httpResult.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);
      httpResult.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
      {
        FileName = file.Name
      }; //attachment will force download
      return httpResult;
}
```

The raw file itself is kept in the byte[] of `file.Bytes`.

And here's a JavaScript function that calls it:

```js
get(fileId, fileName) {
    return this.httpFetch.fetch(`${this.apiRoot}/v1/files/${fileId}`)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(data => {
        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
          window.navigator.msSaveBlob(data);
        else {
          var link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
          link.download = fileName;
          document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
          link.click();
        }
      });
  }
```

Here's a preview of the payload according to Chrome network tools. Seems kind of empty to me...
[image]

The type and filename are correct and it does auto-download, but I end up with a file that's 336 bytes and unreadable.

What am I missing here?

**More Info:** `httpFetch` is a wrapper of `fetch` by Aurelia (aurelia-fetch-client). I'm using Aurelia as my front-end framework.

Comment: What is `this.httpFetch.fetch`? Is it just a wrapper of `fetch`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox correct. It's a wrapper of `aurelia-fetch-client`.

Comment: `msSaveBlob` is a [non-standard obsolete method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveBlob) Are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for the advice. Considering the above doesn't work, I'm all for a better solution.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239154/saving-an-image-blob) may help?

Comment: Tried .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(data => {
        saveAs(new Blob([data], { type: 'image/png' }), fileName);
      });
Ended up with same "bank" 336 bytes unreadable object.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why my solution above didn't work, but some other tests have revealed that the problem is more likely than not in the back-end C# WebApi controller method as my payload can be seen missing... well... the file which is odd.

I've gone for a simpler solution, namely:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
      var file = await _api.GetFileAsync(id);
      var obj = new
      {
        file.Name,
        file.ContentType,
        Base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(file.Bytes)
      };

      return new OkObjectResult(obj);
}
```

Notice how I'm returning an anonymous object with the name, content type and base64 string representation of the file. Pairing this with a solution on [base64 to blob in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) solves the problem nicely with minor alterations to the `get` JavaScript function:

```js
let blob = this.base64toBlob(data.base64String, data.contentType);

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = fileName;
document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
link.click();

resolve(blob);
```