# Download a Blob in PNG Format

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, blob

First of all, I hope you had a good Christmas holiday!

I specify that I am a beginner in JS, hence my possible eccentric attempts to try to download my Blob in PNG.

**My problem is to export all the graphic content of a DIV in pdf or image format by clicking on a button**(the class name of the div is always the same)

After some research I understood that I had to convert the div to canva to be able to download it.
I tried to adapt the code from this post:
[How to take screenshot of a div with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-with-javascript)

But when I click on the button nothing happens despite my various modifications and tests ...

Here is a preview of my code :

```html
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Export Visualisation QS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="qvt-sheet-container">
        <h1>EXPORT PNG</h1> 
        <img src="Logo-Qlik.png">
    </div>
    <a id="link"><button id="btn-export-qs">Export PNG</button></a>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js">
var a = document.getElementById("link");
function export_feuille() {
    $("#btn-export-qs").click(function() {
        html2canvas($(".qvt-sheet-container"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                //theCanvas = canvas;
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    //saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png");
                    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = "export_qs.png";
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                });
            }
        });
    });
};

document.getElementById("btn-export-qs").addEventListener ("click", export_feuille, false);

</script>
</html>
```

If anyone could educate me on what is wrong or point me in a direction I would be very grateful :)

Comment: I don't think should have been closed as a dupe of an inline script question, and now I can't add my answer. But here's what I did (no libraries): https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211735/4946681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see some of the code in your code is redundant.

In your code

```
document.getElementById("btn-export-qs").addEventListener ("click", export_feuille, false);
```

The above code means you have added click event for the button. When the button is clicked it calls the `export_feuille` function, in `export_feuille` you use jQuery to do this again, which is not reasonable.

You wrap a `<button>` in `<a>`, When the button is pressed will use the a tag to trigger the download event, you don't need to. Try the following:

Html: I removed `<a>`

```
<div class="qvt-sheet-container">
    <h1>EXPORT PNG</h1>
    <img src="your-image.jpg" style="width: 150px;height: 150px">
</div>

<button id="btn-export-qs">Export PNG</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#btn-export-qs").click(function () {
    html2canvas(
        document.querySelector('.qvt-sheet-container'),
        {
            allowTaint: true,
            useCORS: true
        }
    ).then(canvas => {
        download(canvas)
    })
});

const download = function (canvas) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'filename.png';
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL()
    link.click();
}
```

Full code [here](https://codepen.io/lam-td/pen/qBPPVbJ)